# Triangular matrices in Prolog

Tags: matrix, prolog

I am trying to write a program that identifies upper triangular matrices. I am quite new to Prolog and i would like your assistance on this.

Considering a matrix as a list of lists, where each list is a matrix row,
how can I do it with basic predicates only, such as *append*, *reverse*, *prefix*, *sublists*, *length* etc ? (will not probably use all these predicates but just to give you an idea)

My attempts failed, mainly because I cannot access the elements of each list/row properly.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/146185/755, https://stackoverflow.com/q/70143031/781723.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SWI-Prolog, you can use the predicate [nth0/3](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=nth0/3) to access elements of a list (indexing from 0).

For example, to access the element in the *third column* (**J** = 2) of the *second row* (**I** = 1) of matrix *M*, you can ask:

```
?- M = [[10, 20, 30], [0, 40, 50], [0, 0, 60]], nth0(1, M, R), nth0(2, R, C).
M = [[10, 20, 30], [0, 40, 50], [0, 0, 60]],
R = [0, 40, 50],
C = 50.
```

So, you can define the following predicate to access elements of a matrix:

```
element(I, J, M, C) :-
    nth0(I, M, R),
    nth0(J, R, C).

matrix([[10, 20, 30],
        [ 0, 40, 50],
        [ 0,  0, 60]]).
```

Example:

```
?- matrix(M), element(I, J, M, X).
M = [[10, 20, 30], [0, 40, 50], [0, 0, 60]],
I = J, J = 0,
X = 10 ;

M = [[10, 20, 30], [0, 40, 50], [0, 0, 60]],
I = 0,
J = 1,
X = 20 ;

M = [[10, 20, 30], [0, 40, 50], [0, 0, 60]],
I = 0,
J = 2,
X = 30 ;

M = [[10, 20, 30], [0, 40, 50], [0, 0, 60]],
I = 1,
J = X, X = 0 ;

M = [[10, 20, 30], [0, 40, 50], [0, 0, 60]],
I = J, J = 1,
X = 40 ;

M = [[10, 20, 30], [0, 40, 50], [0, 0, 60]],
I = 1,
J = 2,
X = 50 
...
```

Now that you know how to access the elements, I think you can find a way to solve your problem.

**Hint**: Use the predicate [forall/2](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=forall/2) to define this rule in Prolog:

```
A matrix M is upper triangular if 
   For every element Xij of M such that j<i, 
   we have Xij = 0.
```

**EDIT** Another possible solution, using `append/3` and `length/2`, is:

```
elem(I, J, M, X) :-
    append(Prefix1, [Row|_], M),
    append(Prefix2, [X|_], Row),
    length(Prefix1, I),
    length(Prefix2, J).
```

Examples:

```
?- matrix(M), elem(1, 2, M, X).
M = [[10, 20, 30], [0, 40, 50], [0, 0, 60]],
X = 50 ;
false.

?- matrix(M), elem(I, J, M, X).
M = [[10, 20, 30], [0, 40, 50], [0, 0, 60]],
I = J, J = 0,
X = 10 ;

M = [[10, 20, 30], [0, 40, 50], [0, 0, 60]],
I = 0,
J = 1,
X = 20 
...
false;
```

Comment: Thank you.. yes this makes sense.. I can finish that now ! .. One last question, apart from  "nth0/3", can I do it using more basic/stanard predicates, like "append", as well ? The "nth0/3" is of course more direct, but if possible I would like to see also the "idea" behind this appoach.

Comment: @john_b Please, see section EDIT in my answer!

Comment: Thank you for the edit ! Finally, I also attempted to do it without "forall" by typing "is_upper(M) :- length(M,N), I<N, J<I, elem(I,J,M,X), X is 0." but it returns "error".. Could you please advise here as well ? @slago

Comment: @john_b The error is due to the fact that variables `I` and `J` are not instantiated when conditions `I<N` and `J<I` are evaluated in the rule's body. You must instantiate these variables, with the goal `elem(I,J,M,X)`, before evaluating these conditions. Anyway, that won't be enough to get the correct answer (you still need to use something equivalent to `forall/2`).

Comment: Ok.. thank you for the advice.. I also wrote the below but the "lower_elements" returns empty list always.. Do you think if the "lower_elements" worked (do not know how), the whole program would eventually work for upper diagonal matrices ? @slago
- `elem(I,J,M,X):- etc`


- `lower_indices(M, L):- findall([I,J], (elem(I,J,M,_),I>J), L).`


- `lower_elements(M,E) :- findall(X,(elem(I,J,M,X),lower_indices(M,L),[I,J]=L),E).`


- `is_upper(M) :- lower_elements(M,K), sumlist(K,N), N is 0.`

Comment: @john_b I don't think so. Observe that `sumlist([-1,2,-1],0)` is true, but this does not mean that the elements in the list `[-1,2,-1]` are all equal to `0`.

Comment: yes.. you are right  @slago